# Binary to String Converting

Tags: php

I have binary string :

```
$header="€$1„—™U"; // number between quotes
```

the equivalent ASCII value should be :

```
$number = 63158024318497
```

I tried the for each as below:

```
for ($x = 4; $x <= 11; $x++) {
$number .= ($header[$x]>>4);
$number .= ($header[$x]&0x0F); 
}
```

not give the number, gives all 0000000000
Where I made mistake ? maybe need to use different way ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? [**`This`**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#b0Vjb8Dqn) test returns `0100000000000000`.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.3.29

Comment: Actually the header string is binary and each nibble have number value.    €$1„—™U = 63158024318497
for ($x = 4; $x <= 11; $x++)  should be  for ($x = 4; $x <= 7; $x++) 
I copied by mistake from few line above of same code.